# How to read Kubent output?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using [Kubent](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble/) to diagnose API deprecation before upgrading my Kubernetes cluster. I am having hard time finding information on how to properly read the programs' output.

```
-----------
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.22 <<<
-----------
KIND                             NAMESPACE         NAME                                       API_VERSION                            REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
ClusterRoleBinding               <undefined>       kubernetes-dashboard                       rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1      rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 (1.8.0)
CustomResourceDefinition         <undefined>       authorizationpolicies.security.istio.io    apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1           apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
```

Notice the Column **REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)**, which created my confusion because k8 is far from 1.8.0 version. Also, the `Deprecated APIs...` message suggest that those Endpoints enclosed in `<<>>` will be deprecated in the last release.

So, may you please explain how should this output be interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

Kube No Trouble ([kubent](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble)) has a defined set of [rules](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble/tree/master/pkg/rules/rego) which are used to determine deprecated APIs.

For example, below we can see the [rule](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble/blob/1ce0aa95059198f82e87bef3ba7a387db553beda/pkg/rules/rego/deprecated-1-22.rego#L89) for `ClusterRoleBinding`:

```
    "ClusterRoleBinding": {
        "old": ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"],
        "new": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
        "since": "1.8",
    },
```

The `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` API has been promoted to `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` in the **v1.8** and this is the reason this specific Kubernetes version is mentioned in the rule above (see: [Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122)).

Additionally, please note that the `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` API version of ClusterRole, ClusterRoleBinding, Role, and RoleBinding is no longer served as of **v1.22**.

Comment: So, the `since` part doesn't refer to the Kubernetes version itself but to the API's version, as far as I can understand. Because I see we are log way from a Kubernetes v1.8. Is it right?

Comment: It refers to the Kubernetes version from which you can use the new API. 
However, you can still use the older API until it is removed (up to version 1.22 in this case).

Comment: Sorry, but there's no Kubernetes v1.8 and I don't believe the k8 dev team is planning deprecations 5 or 10 years from now.

Comment: Please take a look at this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/49642), you can also find information about `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` &  `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` in the [CHANGELOG-1.8.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.8.md).